# Como diminuir o tamanho do texto numa ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Gostaria de saber como diminuir ou aumentar o texto do `ListView`.
No `TextView` existe a propriedade `android:textsize="15";`, qual seria a propriedade equivalente ao `textsize` no `ListView`?
Tenho muitas informações para colocar nele e por isso colocar um `textsize` menor resolveria meu problema .

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ltsunidades"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtselunidade"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnsairmenu"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtselunidade"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtselunidade" 
    android:textsize=???
/>
```

A propriedade acima `android:textsize` não funciona no `ListView`.

Comment: Recomendo [revisar sua pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/125330/edit), principalmente a primeira frase que está confusa. Além disso recomendo explicar um pouco melhor o problema e colocar mais tags para que as pessoas saibam do que a pergunta se trata sem precisar entrar nela. Acredito que seja sobre desenvolvimento `Android`, certo? Coloque pelo menos a tag `#android` na pergunta.

Comment: Reafirmo o que o @DanielDutra disse, a sua pergunta está bem confusa e necessitando de edição. Se consegui entender algo, você quer diminuir o tamanho do texto de cada item que está no listview, certo? Se for isso, você tem que adicionar esse atributo "android:textsize" no <TextView> usado nos layout dos itens. Por favor, confirme se é essa sua dúvida que tento explicar melhor em uma resposta mais detalhada.

Comment: não   eu tenho um listview que ira receber uma grande quantidade de informações... eu apenas queria que eu pudesse diminuir a fonte do listview   .. provavelmente ela tem um tamanho padrão do android...  eu apenas queria diminuir essa font..  desculpe se não consegui passar o que realmente quero..  e que no editext  ou no textview eu consigo altera o tamando da fonte   aumentando ou diminuindo o mesmo .. mas no listview não existe essa opção.

Comment: Pelo que entendi acho que o `ListView` é basicamente uma lista de `TextView`, dessa maneira você precisa alterar o tamanho do texto do `TextView` usado pelo `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ListView é uma representação visual dos dados provenientes de uma fonte de dados. Os dados são convertidos em Views usando um Adapter.

Julgo que você deve estar a usar um *ArrayAdapter*, juntamente com a *View* `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Os dados são apresentados com a "aparência" definida nessa *view*

Nada obriga que tenha de usar essa *view*, você pode definir outra que vá de encontro às suas necessidades.

Crie um novo layout com o nome **list_item_text.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

O código acima é uma cópia do arquivo **simple_list_item_1.xml**, onde é definido `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

Altere-o a seu gosto. Não altere o **id**, ele necessita de ser `@android:id/text1` para que possa ser reconhecido pelo *adapter*.

Por exemplo, para alterar o *textsize* substitua a linha

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
```

por

```
android:textsize="15sp"
```

Para usar este novo *layout* altere a linha:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,oSeuArray));
```

para:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_text, oSeuArray));
```

Comment: consegui .. obrigado era exatamente isso que eu queria

Answer (score 0):

No ListView realmente não há esse atributo, porque o ListView é na verdade (e obviamente) uma lista de views e você vai ter que fazer as customizações que você deseja diretamente nas views. Dentro da cada uma das views da sua ListView deve ter um TextView para exibir os dados, então, você irá adicionar esse atributo no TextView ao invés de usá-lo no ListView.